# Titanium: ScrollView loads slowly

Tags: ios, performance, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator

I'm having some problems with how long a Titanium app I am making
takes to load a ScrollView.

Titanium SDK: 3.3.0.GA

I decided to run a test, comparing how long it would take for a titanium app
to load a similar view, and a native built version (iOS).

The test was loading 1000 textfields into a ScrollView.

For the natively built app, it took about 0.850 seconds to load 
on an iPad mini (based on 3 trials).

For the titanium built app, it took about 59.3 seconds to load
on the same iPad mini (based on 3 trials).

Obviously, this is a significant difference. My code for the
Titanium build is below. Is there something I'm missing? Some option that
is making the ScrollView so slow?
59 seconds compared to 0.850 is pretty significant.

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" >
        <ScrollView id="scrollView" layout="vertical"></ScrollView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
}
```

index.js

```
var startTime = new Date();
startTime = startTime.getTime() / 1000;

$.index.addEventListener('postlayout', calculateTimeToLoad);

loadThousandTextFields();

function calculateTimeToLoad() {
    $.index.removeEventListener('postlayout',calculateTimeToLoad);
    var endTime = new Date();
    endTime = endTime.getTime() / 1000.0;

    Ti.API.info("Total time taken:" + (endTime - startTime) + " seconds");
}

function loadThousandTextFields() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        $.scrollView.add(Ti.UI.createTextField({
            hintText: "Hint text"
        }));
    }
}

$.index.open();
```

Note: I am aware of Titanium's ListView, however, based on my experiments with it, it looks like it won't 
work too well with the app I am making, as I need interaction between my various components and the ability to change
them based on that interaction. (For example, having a switch that, upon being turn off, would 
clear a nearby textfield, or fill it with some text. ListViews seem to be very slow in updating views like that. If I'm wrong, please let me know).

Further Note: I tried running the same test on titanium sdk 3.2.3, and it took about 6 seconds as opposed to 59, on the same iPad mini. However, in the app that I am making, the scrollview actually took longer to load.
Thanks

Comment: it took 0.966 seconds at my end. I just copied your code.

Comment: @Dragon What device did you test it on? Was it on a simulator, and if so, what are the specs of your computer? When I try it simulating an iPhone Retina (3.5 inch) on a mac-mini, it takes about 7.5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

In Mobile Application development. You have always remember Use low Memory or need to always clear unused memory.
Here you add approx 1000 textView at a time. That's why. your app going slow.

Please you try this Reference. In this example. when you scroll you table view then it will add next some row. and this will adding one by one according your display.

Example :- https://gist.github.com/mschmulen/805283

Comment: Thanks for the response. That example you showed is pretty interesting - it's probably what I'll end up doing. But this doesn't answer my question. With native code, the 1000 textfields took about 0.850 seconds to load, which is pretty fast. Titanium took about 59.3 seconds with SDK version 3.3.0GA. I was wondering if there was some setting/option I can use so that the 1000 textfields would load faster with Titanium - closer to the 0.850 with the native code, as titanium is supposed to have comparable speed with code written natively for iOS (at least, based on what I've read).